# Uploading a new apk (version2) as an update to .apk(version1) with different keystore

Tags: android

I have developed and published an app(version 1) on Developer console. Unfortunately my OS crashed, so I've lost my Key-store. Now I want to release an updated app (version 2). When trying to update it says "Certificate not matched". So how to update my app (version 2) in the place of app (version 1). I also want to give updates of this app(version 2) to users who are already using my app (version 1). Any suggestions are welcome...! Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Always backup your keystore some place safe and never forget the passwords. Consider this a lesson learnt and be careful next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to update an app is by building it using the same package name and keystore. It's called a keystore for a reason - it's your key to the app and nobody else can get at it. If you've lost it, there's nothing that can be done - even Google wouldn't be able to restore it for you. If you publish on Google Play, it's essential to keep a backup of your keystore to avoid this issue.

Comment: Suppose if i upload the my app(version 2) as a new app, then how can i able to send the updates to users who are already used my app (version 1). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you upload a new app, the best you can do is invite the users of the old one to install the new one but there is no automatic way to do this. Does your app have any functionality whereby you can send notifications to it? Did you collect email addresses of your users? If not, I regret that I don't see any solution.

Comment: Seems to be it would workout for my problem. Thank you somuch Nigelk

Answer (score 1):

If you lost your keystore then you will not be able to release any update to existing app. There's no way to do that. So if you got no backup of your keystore then you are doomed.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news for you - you won't be able to update your app - that's the whole idea with Key-stores.

See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you must continue to sign the updates with **the same certificate** or set of certificates, if you want users to be able to upgrade seamlessly to the new version. When the system is installing an update to an application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly, including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows the update. If you sign the new version without using matching certificates, you must also assign a different package name to the application — in this case, **the user installs the new version as a completely new application**.

In other words - your app won't be treated as an update, rather as a new app.